# DRY on API specifcations?

Tags: architecture, code-reuse, code-smell, dry, schema

When developing a new RESTful application, I generally:

- Define tests
- Define routes  [ e.g.: RESTful CRUD; namespaced on `/api/users` ]
- Define models  [ e.g.: "Users" ]
- Define forms [ e.g.: in JavaScript (AngularJS), HTML5 and CSS ]

Currently thinking about throwing an API explorer into the mix… which would be another bit of double-typing.

---

The best way I can think of for moving forward is:

1. Define new schema once; using [JSON-schema](http://json-schema.org) notation
2. Engineer a code-generator to generate tests; and some random data with correct types for input
3. Develop a code-generator to create RESTful routes from JSON schema
4. Utilise something like metawidget to generate frontend forms from decoupled backend

---

Is this the best way of encouraging DRY; is there a better/alternate way you can think of / industry best practise?

Comment: Not sure if it suits your needs, and this bare link hardly counts as an answer, but perhaps you might look into SPORE: https://github.com/SPORE/specifications

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**